# Filling polygon with png pattern in OpenLayers?

Tags: polygon, openlayers, png

I want to fill a set of polygons with png pattern.

Here is an extract of my code :

```
 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var pattern;
 var imageObj = new Image();

 imageObj.src = data["fichier_hachures"];

 imageObj.onload = function() {
     pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, 'repeat');
 };

  zonageItems.push(new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: pattern
            })
        })
  })
);
```

When I do this I get my polygons filled with black color.

data["fichier_hachures"] : is an object property containing the Base64 string of my png image.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing code from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835929/in-openlayers-3-how-to-fill-the-polygon-with-a-picture-from-a-url), I'm able to provide base64 image content to show a pattern ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k1v6pgs0/))

The issue in my opinion seems to be the fact, you make a call to

```
zonageItems.push(new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: pattern
        })
    })
})
```

outside of `imageObj.onload` function. Due to this, at the moment, you make a call to an image pattern not already loaded because async (hence your black result)

Did you try instead

```
imageObj.onload = function() {
    pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, 'repeat');
    zonageItems.push(new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: pattern
            })
        })
    })
};
```

Comment: Thank you @ThomasG77, after some edits it's now working.

Comment: Just curious, what was the real issue at the end?

Comment: It was a basic issue with variables declaration.

Comment: Now I am facing another issue. I have multiple polygons each one with its own png pattern. But all polygons are displayed with the same png pattern. I believe that is caused by the asynchronous image loading. Any idea to fix this problem ?